# How to hide a tooltip when a checkbox becomes enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to display a tooltip only when a checkbox is disabled. The checkbox becomes enabled when the correct format is entered into an input text field. I am able to display the tooltip when the checkbox is disabled but it will not hide when the checkbox becomes enabled.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
        <div tooltip="Tooltip message">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="view.checkBox"
                   class="nsg-form--checkbox" 
                   ng-disabled="someInput.$invalid"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise to use ng-change to capture the change in checkbox status and ng-if to display the popup when the checkbox returns true. I put together a quick example that should help: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xBEvOq

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="exampleCtrl">
      <input title="{{(disabledStatus?'disabledReason' : '')}}" 
             ng-disabled="displayPopup" type="checkbox" ng-model="checkBox" 
             ng-change="evaluate(checkBox)"/>
      <div ng-if="displayPopup">Insert Popup Code Here!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('exampleCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.evaluate = function(displayPopup) {
    $scope.displayPopup = displayPopup;
    $scope.disabledStatus = false;
    if($scope.displayPopup === true){
      $scope.disabledStatus = true;
      $scope.disabledReason = "You can make up reason here";
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to capture the change from disabled checkbox to enabled in the html? Without having to check the box? So that when a user tries to click on the disabled checkbox but finds a tooltip informing them why it is disabled

Comment: What you are asking is when the user attempts to click on a checkbox that is set to disabled, do not allow the click and instead display a tooltip?

Comment: Yeah. That's it

Comment: And when the checkbox becomes enabled,I want the tooltip to no longer appear. I have the tooltip appearing when the checkbox is disabled but when it becomes enabled due to the user entering a correct input to a text box, the tooltip is still there

Comment: Okay I made some changes, now when you disable the checkbox it will present a hover message on mouse over, is this more what you were after?